# How to make a flash drive with svn software versioning (for windows)?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, svn

So there are some work places where thaay do not use svn git or anething. Thay use flash drives to move code around work<->home and such. So I wonder if it is possible and how to get a flash drive with a folder under svn with server on that wary flash drive.

I would love to have something like come to work place, insert my flash drive, start some `.cmd` svn config file (or auto run), and get svn versioning on top of some folder on that flash drive working to be able to commit/update/restore at least for me only.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this you should leverage a distributed source control system such as git or mercurial.

The main benefit of a distributed system is that you essentially have a copy of the entire source tree on your machine. This allows you to commit/update/restore/branch/anything to your local machine without needing to contact the server.

You can set up a git repository on a flash drive and then commit directly to it, when you’re happy with your changes and have access to the corporate server you can push your changes directly to a central git server. If the organisation uses svn you can also leverage git-svn.

You’ll require different binaries depending on the operating system you are running if you are using windows [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) is a good choice. [Git for OS X](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) is also available and Linux typically will include git with its standard dev packages.

You can also install git directly to your flash drive so you can make changes to your repository from any computer.